# Square Integrability of spherical symmetric wave

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, wavefunction, normalization, spherical-harmonics

In my class we were discussing some wave equation for a spherical symmetric wave $u(t,r)$ and my professor investigated the behaviour of the solutions asymptotics $r \rightarrow \infty$. The solution was written as some series

$$u(t,r) \enspace = \enspace u_0(t) + \frac{u_1(t)}{r} + \frac{u_2(t)}{r^2} + \ldots$$

Now my professor argued, that by requiring square integrability, one finds that $u_0 = 0$. I assume that his reasoning is that the integral

$$\int_{0}^{\infty} dr \ |u|^2 \enspace = \enspace \int_{0}^{\infty} dr \ \Big[ |u_0|^2 + \frac{u_0 \bar{u}_1}{r} + \frac{\bar{u}_0 u_1}{r} + \frac{|u_1|}{r^2} + \frac{u_0 \bar{u}_2}{r^2} + \frac{\bar{u}_0 u_2}{r^2} + \ldots \Big]$$

is finite only if $u_0$ vanishes. **However**, i was under the impression that when dealing with spherical coordinates, the square integrability condition is supposed to be

$$\int_{0}^{\infty} dr \ r^2 \cdot |u|^2 \enspace < \enspace \infty$$

(note the factor $r^2$) and so in fact one must have $u_0 = 0$ AND $u_1 = 0$ in order for this integral to be finite. Is there any wrongthinking on my part?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that it is most likely that your professor was not thinking of multiplying and integrating term by term the series. Instead he was just thinking about the following:

For the given function $u(r,t)$ a necessary, but not sufficient, condition for its square integrability is that is that $\lim\limits_{r\rightarrow\infty} u(r,t)=0$. If the series is uniformly convergent, then we can take the limit term by term so that we must have:
$$\lim\limits_{r\rightarrow\infty} u_0(t)=0\implies u_0(t)=0,$$
however,
$$\lim\limits_{r\rightarrow\infty}{u_1(t)\over r}=0, $$
does not require that $u_1(t)$ be equal to zero in general.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The necessary condition $\lim_{r \rightarrow \infty} u(t,r) = 0$ for square integrability does indeed make sense intuitively. Do you happen to have a proof or a citation on this one?

Comment: Sorry, it is just my thoughts on the matter.

Comment: Proof: If $\lim_{r\to0}u(r)\neq 0$, then there exists an $r_0$ such that $|u(r)|>c>0$ for all $r>r_0$. We then have $\int_{r_0}^b u^2~\mathrm{d}r > \int_{r_0}^b c^2~\mathrm{d}r = c^2(b-r_0)$, which goes to infinity as the endpoint $b\to\infty$.

Comment: @whpowell96 Can you give a proof that the series in question is uniformly convergent?

Comment: @AlbertusMagnus I deleted my previous comment because here a special form of a function is given and I don't know if my comment applies here; it rather was a general note. Regarding your comment: E.g. $1/x$ is not in $L^2([0,1])$.